# How do I get the value of textarea that is created in while loop

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have the problem, that I can't access the value my textareas which are created in a `while` loop of php. I guess that they are not registered in the DOM. Same is for the button that is attached to it.
So I do know, that I have to access the button via jquery with the special event listener because of this dynamically creation. I get all the IDs that I need, but I am not able to get the value of the textarea, even that I can get its correct ID, as it somehow seems to be just empty.
As I can't post a php fiddle in here, here is an example of how it works.

```
                    include"connection.php";
                    $stuff="here is the query";     
                    for ($n = 1; $n <= 13; $n++) {
                    $xy=$con->query($stuff);
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($xy))
                        {
                        $value = $row['value'];
                        echo"<div id='$n' class='antworten'>$value<br>
                              <div id='notizcontainer$n' class='antwortcontainer'>Notizen:</div>
                              <div class='antwortcontainer' id='notizerstellen$n'>Notiz erstellen:<br>
                              <textarea id='notizfeld' class='textarea'></textarea><br>
                              <button id='absenden' class='notizabsenden'>Notiz absenden</button></div>
                              </div>";
                            }
                     }
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.notizabsenden', function(){ //do this bc its not registered and .click() is not working, also I need the click event on the button class to know on which button the event is going on
            var parentid = $(this).parent().attr('id'); //get parentid of button
            var notizid = $('#'+parentid).find('textarea').attr('id'); //find id of textarea of parent 
            var notiz = $('#'+notizid).val(); //this should give me the text of the textarea... but it returns empty/blank
            console.log(notizcontainer); //this turns out correct
            console.log(parentid); //this turns out correct
            console.log(notiz); //this returns empty/blank as if the textarea has nothing in it... which it does
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this even related to PHP itself, or solely to the generated markup?

Comment: _"So I do know, that I have to access the button via jquery with the special event listener because of this dynamically creation"_ - that applies when the elements get created dynamically _on the client side_, after your JS code that binds the event handler has already run. Unless you are loading & inserting the output of your PHP script dynamically _via_ JavaScript, that is not the case here to begin with.

Comment: What you are doing there, makes rather little sense to begin with. You are trying to select an element first, to then get the ID from that element - and then _use_ that ID, to try and select the element by ID again. Completely point- and useless, because you _had_ the element in the first step already.

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried some other jquery commands like .html() and replaced it with other html codes like an input box. I just can't access the textarea values with jquery.

Comment: `.find('textarea').attr('id')` - assuming this got you the value `notizfeld`, then _which_ textarea do you expect `$('#'+notizid)` to select now - considering that you gave all of them the _same_ ID ...?

Comment: @CBroe it doesn't change the fact, that I can't retrieve the value of the textarea(s) even if I have the correct, specific id.

Comment: You never have "the" correct ID, because you invalidated your HTML by _duplicating_ those IDs in the first place. There are _multiple_ of them, and yet you think it was somehow _specific_ - can you see, how that does not make sense already?

Comment: @CBroe I don't. As I get the parentid of the clicked button, I have the specific div id `notizcontainer$n` which has the added $n value and is therefore unique. then I can retrieve the textarea id of this specific div and try to access the value of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249428/discussion-between-pr0cz-and-cbroe).

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that `<textarea id='notizfeld'` is NOT UNIQUE. And that ID is the one you are trying to use, to select the textarea with. Which because you duplicated IDs, will only ever access the _first_ such textarea contained in the whole document.

Comment: You were on a good way already, trying to navigate by the _relation_ elements have to each other in the DOM. And then you messed it up, by falling back on IDs again - without _any need_ to do so. `$('#'+parentid).find('textarea')` would get you access to the _correct_ textarea element already (assuming `'#'+parentid` is correct) - so why are you still messing around with any ID after that ...?

Comment: And `$('#'+parentid)` is of course superfluous in the exact same way - you _have_ the parent element already after `$(this).parent()`.

Comment: In short: What you are doing there, does not need an ID on _any_ of those elements.

Comment: @CBroe `$('#'+parentid).find('textarea').val();` returns empty. I opened a chat for further talks, so we don't spam in the commentsection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the HTML in your PHP loop is re-using the same `id` for multiple elements when they have to be unique. To fix that problem, remove the `id` attributes from all repeated content.

To address the issue of accessing the `textarea` content, you need to use DOM traversal to find the `textarea` related to the `button` which was clicked. To do that you can use a combination of `closest()` and `find()`, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.notizabsenden', function(e) {
  const $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
  const notiz = $btn.closest('.notizerstellen').find('.notizfeld').val();
  
  console.log(notiz);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- generated by your PHP loop... -->
<div class="antworten">$value<br>
  <div class="antwortcontainer">Notizen:</div>
  <div class="notizerstellen">
    Notiz erstellen:<br />
    <textarea class="notizfeld textarea">Lorem ipsum</textarea><br />
    <button class="notizabsenden">Notiz absenden</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="antworten">$value<br>
  <div class="antwortcontainer">Notizen:</div>
  <div class="notizerstellen">
    Notiz erstellen:<br />
    <textarea class="notizfeld textarea">Dolor sit</textarea><br />
    <button class="notizabsenden">Notiz absenden</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="antworten">$value<br>
  <div class="antwortcontainer">Notizen:</div>
  <div class="notizerstellen">
    Notiz erstellen:<br />
    <textarea class="notizfeld textarea">Amet consectetur</textarea><br />
    <button class="notizabsenden">Notiz absenden</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But as I use the `for` loop with the `$n` added to the ID I get only unique IDs like `notizcontainer1` to `notizcontainer13`. I even checked it in the outputted source code. All my textareas are numbered from `notizfeld1` to `notizfeld13`. So there is no doubled ID.

Comment: The `id` on your textarea is not unique, though. Therefore only the content of the first element with that `id` will be read from the DOM.

Comment: So I found out right now, that a script by a coworker cloned these sections and added it somewhere else. My code was right and working, but with the clone the textarea got cloned too which made the ID not unique. I mark this answer as correct, as it shows a nice working fiddle. Thank you for the input.